# Substr(). Add characters for each n digits

Tags: php, mysql, substring

I have my string which may vary in lenght

```
$k= "2013-01-0112:00:002013-01-0212:00:002013-01-0312:00:00";
```

I'm looking for substr(), str_replace() or any other function my return me this

```
$newstring= ('2013-01-01 12:00:00'), ('2013-01-02 12:00:00'), ('2013-01-02 12:00:00')
```

I should use a kind of for each 18 charcters as the dates of the original string may vary.

My intent is to build then a "INSERT INTO" MYSQL query with all the generated dates in the column "date".

```
id    date
null  2013-01-01 12:00:00
null  2013-01-02 12:00:00
null  2013-01-03 12:00:00
```

Comment: Any problem with using [str_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) with a size of 18, then just walking the resultant array to format the date/times with spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split string on every 18th position. Then add space on every value of the array on 10th position.

```php
$k = "2013-01-0112:00:002013-01-0212:00:002013-01-0312:00:00";
$a = str_split($k, 18);
$a = array_map(function($dt) {
    return implode(' ', str_split($dt, 10));
}, $a);
print_r($a);
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/66958)**.

---

If you wish to add character to N-th position:

```php
$k = "2013-01-0112:00:002013-01-0212:00:002013-01-0312:00:00";
echo implode(',', str_split($k, 18));
//            ^                  ^
//        character         N-th position
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/67717)**.