# mysql: Add comma each N characters

Tags: php, string

$string= 2013-01-0112:00:002013-01-0212:00:002013-01-0312:00:00

I would like to get

```
$nexstring= 2013-01-0112:00:00,2013-01-0212:00:00,2013-01-0312:00:00//comma each 18 chars
```

Comment: So how come the answers to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952046/substr-add-caracters-for-each-n-digits) didn't help?

Comment: Your accepted answer is working only if the string has no space... Instead of `wordwrap` you should use `str_split`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `str_split`:

```
$chunks = str_split($string, 18);

$nexstring = join(',', $chunks);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$nextString = implode(
    ',',
    str_split($string, 18)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of splitting string, you can use [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) function.

```
$nexstring = wordwrap($nexstring, 18, ',', true);
```

Comment: Suspect you need to set the `cut` argument to true

Comment: @F0G: This is working only if the string has no space... Instead of `wordwrap` you should use `str_split`.

Comment: @Legionar there is given a fixed string structure and i can't get what you mean saying "this won't work with spaces". OP asked how to insert commas after every N-th character in string and this code does it regardless there are spaces in that string or not.

Comment: @F0G: He may change string and it will not work. `wordwrap` is dividing also by space ` `... Read docs - http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php (second example).

Comment: @Legionar OK, I figured out what you are saying :)

Comment: Sorry, I wasnt speaking english for longer time :)